# Multiple filters using lodash in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that is filtering a large set of objects based on inputs that looks like so:

```
filterLocations(filters) {
  let filteredLocations = _.filter(
    this.state.locations,
    location =>
      location.beds >= filters.min &&
      location.beds <= filters.max &&
      location.baths >= filters.bathrooms &&
      _.indexOf(filters.buildingTypes, location.buildingType.name) !== -1
  );
  this.setState({ filteredLocations: filteredLocations });
}
```

and in another component this is where the filters are set:

```
let filters = {
  min: this.state.min || 0,
  max: this.state.max || 99,
  bathrooms: this.state.bathrooms || 0,
  buildingTypes: this.state.selectedTypes || []
};
```

The first three work fine because the 'default values' are set regardless, so it makes filtering easy. But I am having trouble with figuring out the last part. If I select a `buildingType` it's fine and the filtering works as expected, but obviously if I leave it blank, the `_.index(...)` part tries to sort on nothing, so the resulting array is empty. I was wondering what would be the best way to rework the `_.indexOf(...)` part so I dont have to do something like:

```
buildingTypes: this.state.selectedTypes || ['list all options here']
```

Comment: So you want that to either filter the building type based on the give one OR to just return them all if none is provided ?

Comment: Yeah @G4bri3l, that's correct

Comment: I was looking for some sort of wildcard to use in `indexOf` but if you wanna make the smallest possible change then @Tony answer is the way to go. A different approach would have been to use regular expressions where you can leverage wildcards as default to always match. But I get the feeling that you would rather keep it the way it is than make a whole bunch of changes. In case you are interested in the regex solution let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use a ternary to conditionally include the `indexOf`, and default to `true` without any buildingTypes so the expression will evaluate to true if all of the others are also true?

```
filterLocations(filters) {
  const filteredLocations = _.filter(
    this.state.locations,
    location =>
      location.beds >= filters.min &&
      location.beds <= filters.max &&
      location.baths >= filters.bathrooms &&
      (filters.buildingTypes.length > 0 
         ? _.indexOf(filters.buildingTypes, location.buildingType.name) !== -1
         : true)
  );
  this.setState({ filteredLocations });
}
```

Comment: appreciate it!!